# Softlayer Python Client API - ordering a firewall for hourly VM

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The Public VLAN firewall is too pricy for us.
I am in search for a better fit solution.

Which API function do I use to order a shared hardware firewall? Can I order one for a hourly VM?

What happens if I cancel the VM? Is the firewall canceled as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, **it's not possible to add hardware firewalls for hourly instances** ( You can only add Software Firewall), In case that you have a VM (in this case, monthly VM) and you cancel the VM, the hardware firewall will be canceled with it.

Regarding to **shared hardware firewall**:

- You can have the rules preconfigured (in script), and add them to the
  firewall once that you required (if you don't have any vm with the
  rules configured yet).
- In case that you have an instance already configured with the rules,
  you are able to share these rules between firewalls.

Let me know if you need assistance to create an script to share rules between firewalls or if you wish to order a Monthly VM with hardware firewall. I will be glad to help you.

Comment: We have decided to go along with the dedicated Public VLAN hardware firewall. The issue is that I need my VMs to be assigned to the portable subnet (according to the documentation and the errors I hit if it is not). Do you have an idea how programmatically I ensure the created instances are automatically assigned to the portable subnet?

Comment: My sincerely apologies, it's not possible to assign portable subnet for instances (it should be done manually). You can only assign the primary subnet for the ordering